# How to convert date value from day to Quarter in SAS

Tags: date, sas, datastep

I have a data set like this:

```
date 
01JAN90
01APR90
01JUL90
01OCT90
01JAN91
01APR91
01JUL91
01OCT91
```

I want to convert the date value into

```
date
1990Q1
1990Q2
1990Q3
1990Q4
1991Q1
1991Q2
1991Q3
1991Q4
```

How can I do it in SAS?

Comment: I have added a solution for your datetime issue. Please see to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this :

```
format date yyq.;
```

where "date" is your date variable.

It will do your job.

**Edit:** After the datetime7. error, If your date is in character datetime format, first extract the date using datepart and then apply the format on the date.

```
sasdate = datepart(date);
fmtdate = put(sasdate,yyq.);
```

Here **fmtdate** is your final answer.

see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201247.htm) for format yyq.

see [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245883.htm) for datepart

Hope this finally helps

Comment: I put this code into data step, but it doesn't work.

Comment: use format instead of put, which version of SAS you are using?

Comment: 9.4, I used format, but it shows me the value 9.78E8.

Comment: seems your date in character, mine is working fine , I am using SAS9.2, you have to change the date to numeric first , use first input statement to do it, then apply the format.

Answer (score 0):

For a new character variable:

```
 quarter = put(date, yyq.);
```

To format the same variable which is all you usually need:

```
format date yyq.;
```

EDIT:
To convert a character date to a SAS date use the following:
    sas_date=input(date, anydtdte.);

Comment: The first one shows Invalid numeric data. The second shows nothing change.

Comment: Then your 'date' is most likely a character variable, first convert it to a valid SAS date.

Comment: I have an error that  Width specified for informat DATETIME is invalid, when I use datetime7.

Comment: Where did datetime come from? That's a diff error not related to this question.

Comment: DATETIME7. I don't know what happen.